# DISTINCT datetime in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I am graphing data from a large database (150K+ rows) and some data points have identical timestamps with different price values.

For example:

```
time  => 1502050000
price => 1

time  => 1502050000 // identical timestamp
price => 1.1
```

In the SQL query, I want to ignore duplicate timestamps. I have found that DISTINCT will likely do the job, but I'm stuck with applying this to a datetime field in my database. Here is my working SQL query which pulls in duplicate timestamps.

```
SELECT time, price FROM price_table WHERE time >= '" . $data_from . "' ORDER BY time ASC
```

My goal is to get unique timestamps only, and avoid querying duplicates.

Comment: But, and this may seem obvious, the prices are different.

Comment: If you have two different price for the same datetime you have two rows..

Comment: I appreciate the comments guys, but I am looking to filter only for unique timestamps regardless of whether prices are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT time, MIN(price) as price
FROM price_table
WHERE time >= '" . $data_from . "'
GROUP BY time
ORDER BY time ASC;
```

Of course, this begs the question of what you want for `price` when there are duplicates.

Comment: I would take the first recorded price for simplicity. I'll try your suggestion.